# Image of morphism from $\mathbb{A}^1 \to \mathbb{A}^2$ is closed

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am having trouble finishing this basic exercise in algebraic geometry:

Show that the image of the map $\mathbb{A}^1 \to \mathbb{A}^2$ given by $\phi(t) = (\alpha(t),\beta(t))$ where $\alpha, \beta \in k[t]$ is closed (in the Zariski topology).

I have tried thinking about something like this:

Consider the map $\mathbb{A}^1 \to \mathbb{A}^3$ given by $t \mapsto (\alpha(t), \beta(t), t)$. Then the image is equal to $V(\alpha(x_3)-x_1) \cap V(\beta(x_3)-x_2)$ where $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the coordinates for $\mathbb{A}^3$. This is closed, so I want to somehow restrict this back to $\mathbb{A}^2$, but I am stuck.

Comment: Do you know integral extensions?

Comment: @Mohan sure, just in terms of commutative ring theory though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that your map gives a map a map of $k$-algebras $k[x,y]\to k[t]$, where $X\mapsto \alpha, y\mapsto \beta$. If both $\alpha, \beta$ are constants, the proof is clear. So, we may assume at least one of them is non-constant. Then the kernel is given by a principal ideal $gk[x,y]$, where $g$ is irreducible. Also, the map $k[x,y]/g\to k[t]$ is integral. Use these to show that the image in question is precisely the set of points, $g=0$ and thus Zariski closed.

Comment: +1, this is a good answer. One small addition: to explicitly find $g$, one may use the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) to eliminate $t$ from the two expressions $x-\alpha$ and $y-\beta$.

Comment: Thank you, but can you help a little bit more?

So $g$ is irreducible because the image is a domain, and the map is integral because for example t is a root of $\alpha(T) - \alpha(t)$ if $\alpha$ is not constant?

Then, because we have the map $k[x,y]/g \to k[t]$, we can get that our original map actually goes $\mathbb{A}^1 \to V(g)$, right? But how do we show that it actually hits all of $V(g)$? Is this where the extension being integral comes into play?

Comment: @student_in_training A point on $g=0$ corresponds to a maximal ideal $M$ of $k[x,y]/g$ and integrality says $Mk[t]$ is a proper ideal and thus contained in a maximal ideal $N$ of $k[t]$. Then, clearly, $N\cap k[x,y]/g=M$. Thus the point corresponding to $N$ maps to the point corresponding to $M$. Since $M$ corresponded to an arbitrary point of $g=0$, we are done.